# How to fix "Coult not find Id property. Be sure the accessor method name matches the veriable name" error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I creating "New JPA Controller Classes from Entity Classes" when I press the "FINISH" button and then I get the following error.

[image]
[image]

**Users.java**

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1.exceptions.exceptions.exceptions;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
*
* @author OZGUR-PC
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userName =       :userName")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

public Users() {
}

public Users(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Users(Integer id, String userName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userName = userName;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
        return false;
    }
    Users other = (Users) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)))   {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.mycompany.mavenproject1.exceptions.exceptions.exceptions.Users[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

I need ideas on how I can solve it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post the code of your Entity class. My guess is that you either didn't declare getters/setters or their names don't match the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared an identifier for your entity. For example let's say there is an entity called `Student` with identifier as `studentId` and property `name` then the  entity should be like this, it should have setter and getter methods for your fields:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int studentId;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```